# Xcode Instruments Core Animation Always keeps 60 FPS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am using iPhone5s and iPad mini (both iOS8.1.1).　Even if I don't do any action (touching screen or scrolling pages...) and using any App in iPhone5s,Core Animation always shows around 60 fps.
But When I do same measurement in iPad mini,Core Animation operated correctly.

Is this iPhone5s's problem in software or hardware ?

Comment: Please always post your code to help people help you.

Comment: What do you mean with "operates correctly"? I suspect that Core Animation aims for 60 fps and won't go any faster, even if the hardware were capable of going faster.

Comment: "operates correctly" means if you don't touch iPhone's screen or scroll pages then the Core Animation will show 0 fps.And if you do some action(e.g. scrolling pages slowly ) Core Animation will show 20〜30fps.